# half data insert but remaining data not update that perticular session pass

Tags: php, mysql

there is data entered in foreach loop but not insert into database there is half data insert into database but there is no work foreach loop.....after insert half data , theres not update remaining half data.....why this happen

the code is

```
 <?php
include_once('config.php');
if(isset($_POST["email_verify_btn"])) {

        $email = $_POST["email_verify"];
        $i = 1;
        if(strpos($email,"\n")) {

        $text = explode("\n",$email);

            foreach ($text as $abc) {
                $i++;
                                $status = 1;
                                $c_by = 1;
                                $c_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                                $c_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                                $_SESSION['date_time'] = $c_date;

                                $insert = $connect->query("INSERT INTO `email_verify_list`(`primary_email`,`session`,`status`,`created_by`, `created_date`, `created_ip`) VALUES ('$abc','".$_SESSION['date_time']."','$status','$c_by','$c_date','$c_ip')");   

                                if($insert) {

                                    $select_status = $connect->query("SELECT * from `email_verify_list` where session='".$_SESSION['date_time']."'");
                                    $fetch_selected_status = $select_status->fetch_assoc();

                                    $fetch_email= $fetch_selected_status['primary_email']; 

                                        if(filter_var($fetch_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))  { 

                                            function domain_exists($fetch_email)
                                            {
                                                $domain = substr(strrchr($fetch_email, "@"), 1);
                                                $arr = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);


                                                if ($arr[0]['host'] == $domain && !empty($arr[0]['target'])) {
                                                    return $arr[0]['target'];
                                                }
                                            }
                                            if(domain_exists($fetch_email)){
                                                $domain = substr(strrchr($fetch_email, "@"), 1);

                                                $data = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);

                                                    if($data) {
                                                    $status = "email id is valid";                      
                                                }           
                                                if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {

                                                    foreach ($data as $key1) {

                                                        $host = $key1['host'];
                                                        $target = $key1['target'];
                                                        $target_ip = gethostbyname($key1['target']);

                                                    }

                                                }



                                            } else {
                                              $status = "mx recored not exist";
                                            }

                                            } else {
                                            $status = "not in syntax" ;         
                                            }

                                            $insert_all_data = $connect->query("UPDATE `email_verify_list` SET `host_name`='$host',`target`='$target',`target_ip`='$target_ip',`status`='$status' WHERE session='".$_SESSION['date_time']."'");

                                            if($insert_all_data) {
                                                echo "<script>alert('successfully');</script>";
                                            } else {
                                                echo "<script>alert('!!!!!not successfully');</script>";                                    
                                            }

                            }

                        } 


            }

}
?>

    <form  method="post" action="" > 

<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane padding-20 active slide-left" id="tab1">
<div class="row row-same-height">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="padding-30">
        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
        <label><font size="2">ENTER YOUR EMAIL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></font></label><br>
        <textarea cols="43" rows="9" name="email_verify"  style="border-color:white;border-width:thin;padding:4pt;" multiple/></textarea><br>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="submit" name="email_verify_btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-info"  style="padding:11pt;width:200px;"/><span><b><font size="2">SUBMIT</font></b></span></button>
        </div>
        </div>  <br><br>
        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table width="100%" class="table ">
        <tr class="success">
        <th>PRIMARY EMAIL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></th>
        <th>HOST NAME</th>
        <th>TARGET</th>
        <th>TARGET IP</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 

        $select = $connect->query("SELECT * from `email_verify_list` where session='".$_SESSION['date_time']."' order by id");
        while($row = $select->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['primary_email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['host_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['target']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['target_ip']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: if it is larger database than verify that it does not exceeds default execution time

Comment: no there is no large database .........there is work completely but not work after this   if($insert) { } ......error is  Notice: Undefined variable: host in C:\wamp64\www\email_verify\index.php on line 70...........Notice: Undefined variable: target in C:\wamp64\www\email_verify\index.php on line 70........Notice: Undefined variable: target_ip in C:\wamp64\www\email_verify\index.php on line 70

Comment: some how your code does not reach where you have assigned values to those variables. Trace code, in which condition it fails

Comment: in `$insert_all_data` query values of PHP variables are not available which you have assigned i.e. `$host = $key1['host'];` and rest of those

Comment: there is no work.....

Comment: echo the update query and check whether values are available or not. As per your warning message data is not there in query

Comment: there is problem as it is .....can't work